# Why show error IllegalStateException when setting MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, android-camera

My code setting  MediaRecorder, it show error at row set Quality

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

   // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
   mCamera.stopPreview();
   mCamera.unlock();
  mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

  mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
   try {
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                        + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
   } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG",
                        "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
   }
```

Ex:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:366)
    at jp.osaka.E028.prepareVideoRecorder(E028.java:1441)
    at jp.osaka.E028.access$16(E028.java:1403)
    at jp.osaka.E028$6.onClick(E028.java:344)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why show error IllegalStateException when setting MediaRecorder?

Comment: Post your stacktrace, please.

Comment: You need to change `e.getMessage()` to `e.fillInStackTrace()`. Then, post your stacktrace here!

Comment: I have provided an answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually you do `mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat()` twice: One time explicitly and afterwards `mMediaRecorder.setProfile()` tries to do it again as you can see in your stacktrace.

The Android Media Recorder has a very low robustness for things like that.

So remove the line that says

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat();
```

and the error should go away. And btw. remove

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```

which is what `mMediaRecorder.setProfile()` has already done as well.

Comment: Can i set setVideoFrameRate when used mMediaRecorder.setProfile()?

Comment: Probably yes. The video frame rate is part of the camcorder profile so you don't need to set it, but from my past experience the frame rate is used by most cameras only as a maximum value and the actal frame rate is set by the camera itself based on the actual conditions, for example the available light. So this parameter is quite uncritical for the success of the recorder start.

Comment: You're a genius mate. Puzzling about even after reading all the official documentation by Google.


Yeap, `recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH))` does already set the AudioEncoder and VideoEncoder for you already.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to release the camera object before the MediaRecorder start, with something like:

```
private void releaseCamera() {
   if (myCamera != null) {
      // Release the camera object so other classes can use it.
      myCamera.release();
      myCamera = null;
   }
}
```

Call the above method before you start your MediaRecorder methods.

**IMPORTANT**: Also, the methods below MUST be called in this order:

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640,480);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

The important bits here are that `setVideoEncoder` and `setAudioEncoder` are called last.

Comment: If camera =null , how record video?

Comment: No, I mean doing the above before `mMediaRecorder.start();`. I can't see from your post that you have this method declared. But it won't work without it.

Comment: If i close 3 row: setOutputFormat,setAudioEncoder,setVideoEncoder , it will work, But I want setting for them.

Comment: Illegal State Exception: it not allow setting the same my code.

Comment: Ah, I see. You may need to move the mMediaRecorder's methods inside your `try/catch` and see what errors are returned (if any). The three methods you mentioned will depend on the Android API and whether your device physically support the modes declared within those methods. You may end up including another third-party library to do what you want e.g. ffmpeg.

Comment: In doc , it only requires Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)

Comment: Have you got these permissions set in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

Comment: Yes, if i close 3 rows: setOutputFormat,setAudioEncoder,setVideoEncoder , I record video ok. but format not correct with requires.

Comment: Also, if you use the `CamcorderProfile`, then set your the following methods in this order: 1) setOutputFormat, 2) setVideoSize, 3) setVideoEncoder and 4) setAudioEncoder. Note: The `setVideoSize` method MUST be called before the `setVideoEncoder` method. See my updated answer above. Note: This important information may not be listed in the docs.

Comment: It should. I just setup a quick and dirty project and it's working fine for me. What's not working for you - please elaborate.

Comment: i had move setProfile and setVideoFrameRate go to before set...Encoder , But it still show error:  IllegalStateException

Comment: Can you update your post above with the latest changes to codes you've made so I can see what you did.