# java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to record sound using microphone. The code works perfectly on **Samsung Note 2 (N7100)** however I receive some errors on some devices. What is the mean of these errors? My codes below here. Thanks in advance.

```
    private void startRecording() {
    CharSequence now = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Date());
    String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "The Looppad"
            + File.separator + now + ".3gp";
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mRecorder.start();
    record.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    isRecording = true;
}
```

**Errors:**

*Error on General Mobile Android 4.2*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at org.uusoftware.thelaunchpadhouse.ActivityFutureHouse.m(Unknown Source)
at org.uusoftware.thelaunchpadhouse.ActivityFutureHouse.onOptionsItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
at android.support.v4.b.ab.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.ag.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.n.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.as.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.m.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Error on LG G2 Android 4.4*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_start(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:758)
at org.uusoftware.thelaunchpadhouse.ActivityTechnoHouse.m(Unknown Source)
at org.uusoftware.thelaunchpadhouse.ActivityTechnoHouse.onOptionsItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2644)
at android.support.v4.b.ab.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.ag.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.n.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.as.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.m.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the errors. Later some with the same problem will be able to find this post.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877833/why-show-error-illegalstateexception-when-setting-mediarecorder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640734/mediarecorder-ioexception-prepare-failed

Comment: Thank you for response but both of them is not related my problem.

Comment: ِCould you find the solution? Would you please post it if you could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

These codes solve my problem:

```
private void startRecording() {
    isRecording = true;
    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = getMaxSupportedSampleRate();
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        NoiseSuppressor.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
        AutomaticGainControl.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
        AcousticEchoCanceler.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
    } else {
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setParameters("noise_suppression=auto");
    }
    int i = recorder.getState();
    if (i == 1) {
        recorder.startRecording();
        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    record.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}

private int getMaxSupportedSampleRate() {
    final int validSampleRates[] = new int[]{48000, 44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};
    for (int i = 0; i < validSampleRates.length; i++) {
        int result = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(validSampleRates[i], AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (result != AudioRecord.ERROR && result != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && result > 0) {
            return validSampleRates[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    int read = 0;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see full code on [Github](https://github.com/aykutuludag/TheLooppad/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/uusoftware/thelaunchpadhouse/ActivityDeepHouse.java)